# text to speech program for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, text-to-speech

Is there a program for text to speech that runs in Ubuntu Linux? Preferably not under wine.

--Edit

Sorry for the delay. My schedule this semester is a whirl wind. anyway. I've got the programs mentioned below. But i should clarify what I'm searching for. I'm Dyslexic. Reading is difficult for me. But when I have the text read a-loud to me it does wonders. The school provides all my text books in a digital form, so I need something I can just drop a large chunk of text (which may or many not be structured very cleanly. some times the text comes with all sorts of random gibberish that has caused several text to speech programs on windows crash on me before.) and have it read it to me.

Thanks, again, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu includes [Festival](http://www.festvox.org/) (`festival` package and perhaps other `fest...`) and [Espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) (`espeak` package). For GUI integration, look at [Orca](http://live.gnome.org/Orca) (`gnome-orca` package).

Voices for languages other than English can be hard to come by. Espeak comes with English only, and Festival comes with voices in Czech, English, Finnish, Hindi, Italian, Marathi and Telugu. Both Espeak and Festival can be made to work with voices from the [Mbrola](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/) project, which are free as in beer but not as in speech.

In the spirit of teaching a man to fish, I'll mention a little-known feature of the Debian/Ubuntu package system. Unfortunately, it's not available in Ubuntu's default package manager (synaptics), but it is available in the text mode package manager aptitude. Install the `debtags` package, then in aptitude select “Views | New Debtags browser”. This shows available packages by tags; the `sound::speech` tag (i.e. expand the `sound` catagory then its `speech` category) lists speech synthesis software.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few, I personally use [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/).

- [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/)
- [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/)
- [epos](http://epos.ure.cas.cz/)

// off topic but if you use [ossv4](http://developer.opensound.com/) it's hard to use espeak directly, so here's the bash function i use :

```
say() {
        echo -n $* | espeak --stdin --stdout -v+f6 | play -q -
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
I've tried epos, espeak and festival but I haven't found a way to make it sound like a girl.
Is it possible?

Comment: Festival come with one female voice - but adding more voices is straightforward - see http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/manual/festival_24.html#SEC98

Comment: also espeak comes with several female voices, try `espeak -v+f1` (`+f1 -> +f6`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Festival](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TextToSpeech).

[Orca](http://live.gnome.org/Orca) is another alternative